# What is the motivation for cross validation on feature selection preprocessing?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection

I saw several articles and examples of feature selection (wrapper & embedded methods) where they split the samples data into train and test sets.

I understand why we need to use cross-validate (split the data into train &test set) for building and testing the score of the models (actual prediction of the propose algorithm).

But I can't understand what is the motivation to do so for feature selection ?

There are no true results of which features we need to choose, so how can it improve the process of feature selection  ?

What is the benefit ?

Answer (score 0):

Most feature selection methods, such as wrapper models, require comparing model's performance under the use different feature combinations.

Cross-validation provides a more robust means of comparing the performance when different features subsets are used, and, therefore, a more robust feature selection process. For example, if K-folds cross-validation is used, comparison will be based on the average of the errors from different folds of data, and, therefore, a subset is selected that would result in the smallest generalization error.

Also, optimal hyper-parameters are not necessarily the same for different feature combination. Cross-validation helps with tuning and, therefore, a more fair comparison.

[This](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8610148) is also an informative resource on this topic.